# Kafka Sink Connector without a primary key

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to write to a sink connector that will update a record in a SQL-Server database based on a where clause?

```
    user
    - ssn int (pk)
    - name varchar
    - email varchar (no index)
    - status
```

the topic will only contain

```
    - name
    - email
    - new_status
```

I would like the sink connector to perform something similar to the sql

```
update user
set status = <new_status>
where email = <email>
```

Is this possible with a sink connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these properties if you want to update/upsert by email field

```
"pk.mode": "record_value",
"pk.fields": "email"
```

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#writes

You can see there, WHERE query cannot be customized like for the source connector

Comment: Actually I'd like to do a slightly more complex version in the where clause. e.g. "where <email> like '%@foo.com'". Is this type of query possible?

Comment: Not from the sink connector, no